# Stacked histogram of discrete values

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Having some data like

`OrderedDict([(734242, [1, 0, 1]), (734243, [0, 0, 1]), (734244, [0, 0,
0]), (734245, [3, 0, 1]), (734246, [0, 0, 0]), (734247, [0, 0, 0]),
(734248, [0, 0, 0]), (734249, [0, 0, 0]), (734250, [0, 0, 0]), (734251,
[0, 0, 0]), (734252, [0, 0, 0]), (734253, [0, 0, 0]), (734254, [0, 0,
0]), (734255, [0, 0, 0]), (734256, [0, 0, 0]), (734257, [0, 0, 0]),
(734258, [0, 0, 0]), (734259, [1, 0, 0]), (734260, [0, 0, 0]), (734261,
[0, 0, 0]), (734262, [0, 0, 0]), (734263, [0, 0, 0]), (734264, [0, 0,
0]), (734265, [0, 0, 0]), (734266, [0, 0, 0]), (734267, [0, 0, 0]),
(734268, [0, 0, 0]), (734269, [0, 0, 0]), (734270, [0, 0, 0]), (734271,
[0, 0, 0]), (734272, [0, 0, 0]), (734273, [0, 0, 0]), (734274, [0, 0,
0]), (734275, [0, 0, 0]), (734276, [0, 0, 0]), (734277, [0, 0, 0]),
(734278, [0, 0, 0]), (734279, [0, 0, 0]), (734280, [0, 0, 0]), (734281,
[0, 0, 0]), (734282, [0, 0, 0]), (734283, [0, 0, 0]), (734284, [0, 0,
0]), (734285, [0, 0, 0]), (734286, [0, 0, 0]), (734287, [0, 0, 0]),
(734288, [1, 0, 0])])`

(which is already a stacked-like type of histogram),

how would I create a stacked histogram similar to this

[image]

but with the values on the x axis taken from the key of the OrderedDict, and the values found at that key as the heights of the individual stacked segments?

For example, `(734245, [3, 0, 1])` should make matplotlib display a bar of height 3 at the x coordinate 734245, then on top of it a segment of height 0 (not visible), and another segment of height 1 on top of it, making the final bar 4 in height.

The input data could get big, with around 10k x coordinates, so performance is important.

Any library is welcome, matplotlib is not compulsory.

Comment: ```class Plotter:
    def get_stacked_histo_plot(self, data, colors):
        globalplot = None
        for xpos, vals in data.items():
            p_ampl = 0
            for binnum, l_ampl in enumerate(vals):
                p = polygon([(xpos-0.5,p_ampl), (xpos-0.5,l_ampl+p_ampl), (xpos+0.5,l_ampl+p_ampl), (xpos+0.5,p_ampl)],rgbcolor=colors[binnum])
                p_ampl = l_ampl+p_ampl
                if globalplot:
                    globalplot += p
                else:
                    globalplot = p
        return globalplot```

Comment: (using sagemath) which works, but I was wondering if it could be done better

Answer (score 0):

This is a very inefficient way to do things, but it could help you get started.

```
a = dict([(734242, [1, 0, 1]), (734243, [0, 0, 1]), (734244, [0, 0,
0]), (734245, [3, 0, 1]), (734246, [0, 0, 0]), (734247, [0, 0, 0]),
(734248, [0, 0, 0]), (734249, [0, 0, 0]), (734250, [0, 0, 0]), (734251,
[0, 0, 0]), (734252, [0, 0, 0]), (734253, [0, 0, 0]), (734254, [0, 0,
0]), (734255, [0, 0, 0]), (734256, [0, 0, 0]), (734257, [0, 0, 0]),
(734258, [0, 0, 0]), (734259, [1, 0, 0]), (734260, [0, 0, 0]), (734261,
[0, 0, 0]), (734262, [0, 0, 0]), (734263, [0, 0, 0]), (734264, [0, 0,
0]), (734265, [0, 0, 0]), (734266, [0, 0, 0]), (734267, [0, 0, 0]),
(734268, [0, 0, 0]), (734269, [0, 0, 0]), (734270, [0, 0, 0]), (734271,
[0, 0, 0]), (734272, [0, 0, 0]), (734273, [0, 0, 0]), (734274, [0, 0,
0]), (734275, [0, 0, 0]), (734276, [0, 0, 0]), (734277, [0, 0, 0]),
(734278, [0, 0, 0]), (734279, [0, 0, 0]), (734280, [0, 0, 0]), (734281,
[0, 0, 0]), (734282, [0, 0, 0]), (734283, [0, 0, 0]), (734284, [0, 0,
0]), (734285, [0, 0, 0]), (734286, [0, 0, 0]), (734287, [0, 0, 0]),
(734288, [1, 0, 0])])


for b in a:
    plt.bar(x=b, height=a[b][0], color='r')
    plt.bar(x=b, height=a[b][1], bottom=a[b][0], color='b')
    plt.bar(x=b, height=a[b][2], bottom=a[b][1], color='g')
```

[image]

To improve the efficiency, you'd have to transform your dictionary into an array. All the parameters `x=`, `height=`, and `bottom=` can take an array as argument. You could then reduce the code to 3 `plt.bar()` calls.